# How to select Numeric UpDown value programmatically in Winforms?

Tags: c#, numericupdown

I want to select the available value within the numeric up/down control using c#

[image]

and in general if we **double click** within the control then we get the following(the entire text gets selected colored Blue in BG)

[image]

Now my question is How do I achieve this pro-grammatically??

---

My trails so far :

**Focus();**

**Select();**

this doesn't seem to work, any help on this regard would be much appreciated, Thanks..:)

Comment: Can you do a `.SelectAll()` ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectall.aspx

Comment: there's no such function called .selectAll() in the Numeric Up Down control

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Select` has an overload that takes two `int`, one for selection start, one for selection length:

```
myNumericUpDown.Select(0, myNumericUpDown.Text.Length);
```

Comment: Be sure to give the NumericUpDown() focus before or after using the above line, otherwise you won't see the selection take effect.

Comment: Indeed, NumericUpDown without focus hides its selection

Comment: @Basuro & Idle_Mind thanks for the quick solution, just tried it works fine but one change required to the above code: instead of Text.Length(), I've used Value.ToString().Length, seems .Text.Length() is not applicable to numeric up down control.

Comment: Have you tried `Text.Length` without the `()`? `Text` property is a string, which always features the `Length` property...

Comment: The NumericUpdown.Text property is hidden because it has no meaning for this control.  This code cannot work reliably.

Comment: Damn. Oversight on my part.

Comment: Seeing the "recent" (2020) edit: Be careful when using the `Text` property in a `ValueChanged` event handler. It will be different from the result of `Value.Tostring()`. To be more precise, `Text` will return the *old* value that was in the control while `Value.ToString()` will return the *new* value. So when the length of the contents changes (because of crossing a magnitude margin, e.g. `9 -> 10` or `1000 -> 999`) you might end up with an incomplete selection or an exception because you're trying to select more characters then the control actually contains.

Answer (score 1):

Do you not just want the `.Value` property of the control? Or are you trying to get it exactly the way it is formatted in the textbox?

Comment: as mentioned above,just looking to select the entire value & not trying to access the value at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

You can get to the TextBox portion of the control through a trick, use the Controls property.  Like this:

```
    var box = (TextBox)numericUpDown1.Controls[1];
    box.SelectAll();
    box.Focus();
```

This would normally be a bit fragile, but it is 99.9% guaranteed that NumericUpDown is never going to change.